# Water level sensors for water pump

Tags: arduino, sensor, waterproof, fluid-pump

I have a "pompe a eau" inside a well of 40 meters length, the water pump doesn't stop if there is no more water in the well and that causes damage to it. So I tought of using  water level sensors just above the hole from where the water pump drains the water, so that when there is no more water I can turn off the circuit so that the water pump stops working.

I have a little knowledge of electronics(but good programming skill, I can program arduino or some other microcontroller without any problem).

So I have looked for water level sensors in eBay and I found [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Liquid-Water-Level-Sensor-Horizontal-Float-Switch-For-Aquariums-Fish-Tank-Pool-/311231357646).

The problem is that the cable lenght is just 400mm, its too short for doing anything with and is this item capable of taking pressure because the "pompe a eau" is going to be 10-20 meters under the water.

Maybe this is not the right sensor for the job?

Comment: If you search the same auction site for "well float switch" or "well pump switch" you'll find sensors better suited for the job.

Comment: See also: [Electrical conductivity to determine reservoir water level to switch on/off pump](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/77002/25328)

Answer (score 3):

Just buy a pump with integral float switch (that's the red thing): -

[image]
<sub>(source: [reuk.co.uk](http://www.reuk.co.uk/OtherImages/pump-with-float-switch.jpg))</sub>

I use a similar one to this to pump waste water from my koi pond 10m up a slope to a drain. It works but, if you don't value your time enough to spend (maybe) $100 then my advice is useless.

Try searching "submersible water pump with integral float switch". Of course the 10m depth means you have to possibly refine the search parameters.

Comment: Can you also get float switches to retrofit to an existing pump? I suppose making the connections underwater is a problem.

Comment: Maybe dangle a float onto the surface of the water and when the water lowers too much a ground level switch will activate (under gravity) and turn the "dry" power off?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of solutions.  As in the other answer, a float switch, a set of sensor wires, a bubbler system, an ultrasonic level height sensor or some radar sensors.  Not enough information to offer a specific answer.

https://www.google.com/search?q=borehole+pump+level+sensor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to monitor the current draw of your pump. As soon as it starts to cavitate the current will change significantly and you can easily program an arduino to monitor that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your asking. I think Immersion type liquid level sensor is a pressure sensor for measuring the liquid level. Based on the principle that the measured hydrostatic pressure is proportional to the height of the liquid, an isolated diffused silicon sensitive element or a ceramic capacitive pressure sensitive sensor is used to convert the static pressure into The electrical signal is then converted into a standard electrical signal by temperature compensation and linear correction. It is generally suitable for liquid level measurement of various media in petroleum, metallurgy, electric power, pharmaceutical, water supply and drainage, environmental protection and other systems and industries.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please take the Tour at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour and How to answer at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. _"I think"_ does not constitute a good answer.