Water level meter with electrodes: earthing and galvanic corrosion
I have a water level meter which uses electrodes.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The circuit detects contact of electrodes with water, at different levels, that go into a 74HC148 priority encoder, that's an active low device. So I have a common positive electrode in the bottom of the tank, each level is driven by a BC547 NPN BJT with collector high through 10 kΩ and emitter to ground. The collector is the input to the priority encoder. So when water touches the electrode connected to the base of the BJT, the small current will switch the BJT on and pull the collector / encoder input low.
So far so good.
Now my question is, I was made aware of a problem with galvanic corrosion, as particularly the lowest electrode will constantly be on with an ever so small current flowing. Even though I drive this at only 3.3 V, the small current will eventually eat up the electrodes.
My question is what I could do about it? Someone suggested to use AC on the electrodes. I suppose I could somehow use a square wave generator and a level shifter to have the common electrode alternate between -3.3V and +3.3V, the BJT bases won't care about the -3.3V, and this would work still if I latch the results on the positive phase with a simple level latch. But this wouldn't really resolve the problem I suppose because during the negative phase, we would need a small current to flow like the base current during the positive phase. I don't know what circuit could do that magic?
Another question is that I could measure the levels only for a short pulse once every 10 seconds or even less. The electrodes are just the points of the same type of wire, so there shouldn't be any galvanic potential between them just from metal differences.
A very related part of the question is also grounding and earthing. The water tanks and pipes are plastic here, so I don't think that system is earthed. But another tank is a cistern made from concrete in the ground, so I suppose that is heavily earthed. I wonder what that would do to our small potential difference between the electrodes, with the common electrode being the positive one? Should I use PNP instead and have the common electrode being ground (and using the intermittent trick would have the corrosion issue mostly under control)? I thought about PNP before but couldn't figure out a way to switch the active low priority encoder.

The AC design has been discussed in this question: Electrical conductivity to determine reservoir water level to switch on/off pump and is really not very easy to manually produce. I would be interested in something that's based on a 555 oscillator maybe. That other question also makes a great case for why this electrode based approach is valid, because it's cheap and easy.

Why not just wait until you have proper access to a schematic editor?

”So I explain in words here and later today I add the schematics.” Please don’t. Your question is unanswerable without a schematic. You can draw your schematic by clicking on Edit and then the schematic symbol.

See this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/77005/25328

You can calculate how much material is being removed by the current flowing. Given the metals involved and their physical dimensions you can work out how long they'll last.

If your problem is galvanic corrosion, one solution might be to use platinum electrodes. Although your up-front costs will be higher, it may pay off in the end due to increased longevity and reliability. However, we lack sufficient information to do a cost benefit analysis for you. You must do that analysis yourself.

When galvanic corrosion is unavoidable the usual solution is to add a sacrificial anode.

Make your sensor electrodes as a PCB and have them gold plated. Easier to source than platinum wire electrodes, and design the board that the electrodes are equally spaced - the electrode array can be easily mounted in the tank and allows the array to be precisely and robustly located.

Here is what I came up with now, normally I believe in putting that into the question to show my own work, but I frequently get scolded because you're not supposed to put your solutions into the question. In some way the question still remains as a question, because the AC circuit might be interesting, but I think I can do without the complex AC design by 2 changes:

Change NPN to PNP sense transistors so that the common electrode can remain on GND (earth) potential and the positive side will be the bases of the sense transistors. Now the common electrode won't be sacrificing itself as an anode constantly on and I can have GND on earth.
Only turn the whole level measurement device on for a very short instant when the microcontroller wants to read the level, which is really in the range of a few millisecond every minute, or even less!


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The "enable" line will be connected to a digital output of the microcontroller and it will set that to HIGH just the moment it wants to read the water level and then shut it off right away.
I figure the vanilla BC547B transistor is enough to power this thing as I compute a  2.65 mA power draw only. I guess I should put a current limiting resistor on the base of Q3 just in case if there was a short that it would not fry the digital output pin of the microcontroller? (Oh boy, I just put a question mark into an answer.)
The gold plating would still be cool, the level spans more than 2 meters, that's not something I do on a PCB, it is an ethernet wire in a 1/2" PVC tube that I am mounting. I could bring that to a gold plating place, but I would need to seal off the insulation so that no water can creep into it.

If you use Darlingtons, you'll be able reduce the current through your electrodes and therefore slow the corrosion. (but you also increase the risk of false readings due to leakage paths from nominally dry electrodes)
